# gcc build behavior when there is are conflicting version of openssl

Tags: c++, gcc, openssl, g++, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a c++ library of mine (which is dependent on [facebook/folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly)) with gcc7. Some important points to note

- Previously I was using gcc 4.8 to build this library
- Since there is ABI incompatibility introduced in gcc 5.2 - I built folly from source (and all other dependent libraries like glog etc.) with gcc 7 - and I am using the updated libraries and shared objects.
- My library uses openssl 1.1 (even previously when it was being built with gcc 4.8), where as folly (the version of folly that I am using) uses openssl 1.0.2

Even with the openssl version incompatibility the build of my library would go through fine with gcc 4.8 with the following warning

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /home/<username>/folly/folly/1000.37.2.1/lib/libfolly.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
```

I get the exact same warning with gcc 7 as well, but my build now fails with the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/<username>/folly/folly/1000.37.2.1/lib/libfolly.a(SSLSessionCacheManager.o): undefined reference to symbol 'SSL_CTX_get_ex_new_index@@libssl.so.10'
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried researching this problem in regards to **DSO missing from command line** - but the solutions mentioned in other questions doesn't seem to be my case.

There are 3 questions that I am seeking to answer here

1. Can openssl version incompatibility be the reason for the build failure?
2. Why would the build succeed in gcc 4.8 but fail on gcc 7?
3. Is there an way to solve this without updating openssl version in folly (I will have to pull in a lot of changes for that - which will require code changes from my side). My library only uses `openssl/md5.h`

Comment: According to your error message, previously you were linking with `libfolly.so`, the shared library, and your second error message indicates that you're linking with `libfolly.a`, the static library. Apples and oranges. You need to figure out why, and link with `libfolly.so` again.

Comment: Sam, the warning is the same in both the cases. I will edit the question for more clarity.

Comment: I repeat: you are linking with `libfolly.a` instead of `libfolly.so`. This is indicated clearly by the shown messages. You obviously didn't get an error from linking with `libfolly.a` instead of `libfolly.so` before, because you weren't. You were linking with `libfolly.so` when it worked. I can't explain the apparent problem any better.